«Выглядещим» или «выглядещем»?

Цитата

Тест может показаться идеально выглядещим при некоторой настройке.
Или

Тест может показаться идеально выглядещем при некоторой настройке.

Заранее благодарю всех ответивших.

Правильно:
Тест может показаться (каким?)  идеально вы/гляд/ящ/им при некоторой настройке.
Управление Т.п. Суффикс ЯЩ причастия.
Глядеть — гляд/ят — гляд/ящ/ий, 2-ое спряжение, ударное окончание (определяется без приставка ВЫ)

Но было близко)

Орфографический редактор вариант предложил...)  Неплохой, да?
